# Minimize number of divisors of an integer within an interval

Tags: algorithm, primes, discrete-mathematics, factoring

I have recently stumbled upon an algorithmic problem and I can't get the end of it. You're given a positive integer N < 10^13, and you need to choose a nonnegative integer M, such that the sum: M*N + N*(N-1) / 2 has the least number of divisors that lie between 1 and N, inclusive.
Can someone point me to the right direction for solving this problem?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/) question. Or possibly [compsci](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). But it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find a prime P greater than N. There are a number of ways to do this.

If N is odd, then `M*N + N*(N-1)/2` is a multiple of N. It must be divisible by any factor of N, but if we choose `M = P - (N-1)/2`, then `M*N + N*(N-1)/2 = P*N`, so it isn't divisible by any other integers between 1 and N.

If N is even, then `M*N + N*(N-1)/2` is a multiple of N/2. It must be divisible by any factor of N/2, but if we choose `M = (P - N + 1)/2` (which must be an integer), then `M*N + N*(N-1)/2 = (P - N + 1)*N/2 + (N-1)*N/2 = P*N/2`, so it isn't divisible by any other integers between 1 and N.